# Any suggestions or improvements?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, do-while

Can I use the for loop to replace the do...while loop in this program? Any suggestion to make this program more simple? This program ask the user to enter their option from 1 to 5 (if choice is another number the program will terminate)
My code:

```
int choice;
    char option;
    printf("You want to know what I'm thinking about you?\n");
    printf("1. Add New Contact\n");
    printf("2. Edit Existing Contact\n");
    printf("3. Call Contact\n");
    printf("4. Text Contact\n");
    printf("5. Exit\n");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("Please choose the above option:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &choice);
    switch (choice)
    {
    case(1) : printf("To add new contact, you need the contact's: First name, Last name and Number");
        break;
    case(2) : printf("To edit, enter new contact's number");
        break;
    case(3) : printf("Who do you wish to call");
        break;
    case(4) : printf("Who do you want to text");
        break;
    case(5) : exit(1);
    default: printf("\n%d is not a valid choice!\n", choice);
        break;
```

Source code:

```
do
{
printf("Enter your choice: ");
scanf(" %d", &choice);
switch (choice)
{
case (1): printf("\nTo add you will need the ");
printf("contact's\n");
printf("First name, last name, and number.\n");
break;

case (2): printf("\nGet ready to enter the name of ");
printf("name of the\n");
printf("contact you wish to change.\n");
break;
case (3): printf("\nWhich contact do you ");
printf("wish to call?\n");
break;
case (4): printf("\nWhich contact do you ");
printf("wish to text?\n");
break;
case (5): exit(1); //Exits the program early
default: printf("\n%d is not a valid choice.\n", choice);
printf("Try again.\n");
break;
}
} while ((choice < 1) || (choice > 5));
return 0;
```

Comment: Please indent your code before posting.

Comment: @Lundin sir, I was about to write the same. :-)

Comment: To begin with, you could merge your successive `printf`: `printf("msg1\nmsg2\n")`

Comment: @Lundin sorry sir but this is just my second question, I don't quite understand your post cause I've already used ctrl+k to post my code

Comment: @Coconop That's a bit subjective, but I don't think he should. Leaving the different statements on separate lines gives readable, self-documenting code.

Comment: @DuyNguyen Click "edit" below your post and fix the indention (spaces in front of each row etc). I have no idea what "ctrl + k" is supposed to do, or in which program it is supposed to do that.

Comment: @Lundin I meant those in the 2nd piece of code. I do agree those in the menu should be left as is.

Comment: @Lundin "ctrl+k" is a shortcut for makring a line as `code sample` here. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Ok, well anyway ctrl+k doesn't magically invoke GNU indent...

Comment: downvote from me. First of all change your question tittle.

Comment: @Lundin nono, it's not about indenting, it's just a shortcut for the `code` markdown. :-)

Comment: Your question title does not describe what you are asking. Here is help on how to ask a question well on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think for this problem replace the "do...while" loop with the "for" loop is well. In the first code (for loop) if the user choose a correct answer the program make 5 times the same operation. Insted in the "do while" the loop stop just when the answer is correct (chose is = 1...2....3...4..or 5). I think that the second code is right
regards

Comment: Yes I saw that so I tried to add an option whether the user want to end the loop immediately cause I just want to try a new way with for instead of using do...while

Comment: ok if you want to use a for loop, you have to insert a second check, if the answer is 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 then "break". In this way the for loop end when the answer is correct

Answer (score 2):

Well, in theory you could, but it wouldn't make any sense. As a rule of thumb:

- Use `for` when the number of iterations are known. (Usually considered easiest to read and usually produces the most effective code.)
- Use `while` when the number of iterations are unknown.
- Use `do while` when the number of iterations are unknown, but you must put the loop condition after the first lap in the loop (for example because you need to evaluate user output).

Comment: Sir, very genuine and helpful suggestions. However, in current context, they behave differntly, isn't it? Can you please review my answer?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I don't know what the program is supposed to do, so I can't tell what's correct program behavior. Maybe 5 iterations are always required, although it seems unlikely. More likely that's just a bug/typo, but who knows.

Comment: @DuyNguyen Be sure to mark an answer as accepted if it successfully answers your question. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, no. As the code is currently written, the major behavioral difference, unless the input is `5`,

- The `for` loop version is guranteed to execute `5` times,
- The `do...while` version depends on the input value for each iteration. for any value less than `1` or greater than `5` will terminate the loop. Otherwise, it will continue looping.

Comment: You could in theory write something obscure such as `for(choise = 0; (choice < 1) || (choice > 5); )` and it would be equivalent. There are no guarantees for how many times it will run. But of course one shouldn't write such icky for loops, as they are hard and unintuitive to read.

Comment: As a comment above told me to add a break if answer=1,2,3,4,5 and it works fine for me. Anyway, thanks for your advice. It helps me a lot sir @Lundin